# kill wpa_supplicant on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, network-manager, aircrack-ng, wpa-supplicant

i want to run Aircrack-ng on Ubuntu touch but i need to kill network-manager and "wpa_supplicant process".
killing network-manager is easy , just run "sudo service network-manager stop" , but after killing "wpa_supplicant" its start immediately.
any idea to kill "wpa_supplicant" on Ubuntu touch? (i was tried most of solutions on Google)

Comment: this is a question rather than an answer - what are you running Ubuntu touch on? Do any of the official devices have wifi card suitable for aircrack or are you using an alfa or similar?

Comment: I'm using build in wifi card of meizu pro 5

Answer (score 0):

For using Aircrack-ng you have to disable all processes that might interfere during operation in monitor (promiscuous) mode. To do so **run the following command** in the terminal:

```
sudo airmon-ng check kill
```

This will check and display all processes that will need to be terminated and also end them.

After restoring to managed mode you might face problems in your Wi-Fi connectivity, even after restarting the service network-manager using`sudo service network-manager start`.

To restore Wi-Fi connectivity you must soft-unblock your desired Wi-Fi interface. To check the status of Wi-Fi interfaces:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

To unblock all Wi-Fi interfaces:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: Hi, airmon-ng check kill shows 2 process , network manager and wpa_supplicant i can kill network manager but after kill wpa_supplicant it will start immediately

Comment: Does the restarting of the process wpa_supplicant create any problems for you while you use aircrack-ng in monitor mode? I use airmon, airodump and aireplay frequently but never face any problems due to restarting of wpa_supplicant process.

Comment: Yes it's says "error while getting interface flags: no such device". Note that the only running process is wpa_suplicant

Comment: Documentation from the Aircrack-ng site suggests to update to the latest version in such a case, so update to the latest version if you already haven't. Also confirm that you are using the correct interface name, use command iwconfig for list of all wireless interfaces.

Comment: I'm in latest version "1.2 beta 3" and i confirm my interface is true, in iwconfig and airmon-ng my interface is wlan0

Comment: If the problem is not solved, I believe then the only option left is to stop the wpa-supplicant daemon. For that remove 2 files in the directory: /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services. In the directory there are 2 files named fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service and fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service. Use sudo mv command to move them to another directory, to create a backup and do not straightaway delete them. After that, reboot and check whether the process wpa_supplicant is still running. If not, then you can use aircrack-ng without any issues, and then restore the 2 files afterwards.

Comment: I was tried, this method doesn't stop wpa_supplicant daemon on ubuntu touch

Comment: try sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51508/discussion-between-50calrevolver-and-iprogramer).

Comment: Systemctl stop wpa_supplicant says faild to get d-bus connection :operation not permitted (with sudo) and second command works but wpa_supplicant still running

Comment: Which Wi-Fi card are you using? For aircrack to work, your Wi-Fi card should support monitor mode in the first place.